# How to realize notification system for huge data?

Tags: php, database, laravel, notifications

Good afternoon, I have a question, hope you can help me with it.

I have two users - UserA (employer), UserB (candidate)

UserA can create filter for candidates, also he must get a notification about new users, which match his filter.

In profile, UserB have 6 steps to change his personal information, so if UserB changes 1 of this 6 steps and new information matches filter, UserA must get notification about it.

So, now it's realized so: I have 2 tables - "users" (id, firstname, lastname) and "subscriptions" (user_id, firstname, lastname)  with almost identical fields, on update UserB details, i compare UserB information from table "users" with fields in table "subscriptions", if it's past i write user_id from "subscriptions" into array, after it i use foreach for this array and send notifications for users in this array. It's work fine if i have 100 users and 2 fields to compare, but how about huge data?

How I can code it more effective for huge data?

For development I use Laravel 4.

Thank you.

Comment: By 'realize' do you mean 'implement'?

Comment: How much is huge data for you?

Comment: @developerwjk yes, sorry for my english :)

Comment: @EmilioGort, filter consists from ~7 tables, in 1 table ~10-15 fields, users 1000-10000.

Comment: with good relation between the tables and inner join you can manage  that data without any problem, 10000 records is a small amount